# Internet Explorer 11 not letting me browse on hover iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, jquery-hover

HTML

```
<div class="test">hover me</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').hover(function() {
        $(this).html('<iframe width="370" height="600" src="http://latimes.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>')


    }, function() {
        $(this).html('hover me')

    });
});
```

I can browse in the iframe on Firefox and Chrome, but not on Explorer. It just sends me back to the front page.

[**JS FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/75pgcm7q/16)

Comment: Works for me, with IE11

Comment: @RowlandShaw are you able to click on links and navigate them?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant when I said it works for me...

Comment: that's weird, I just tried in on my laptop and I still have the same problem. When I click on a link it just refreshes the iframe and starts to flicker. It never takes me to the actual link page.